# Stop/remove bxSlider inside Colorbox popup when popup is closed?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, bxslider

I use colorbox popups with html data, however after closing the popup, I noticed my bxSlider was still outputting the console.log line which is run when the slider moves to the next or previous slide.

I need to disable the bxSlider when I close my colorbox popup. The bxSlider code is inside the html data template (so each time I create/load the colorbox popup, it has the same inline JS for the bxSlider).

My colorbox is created with this code:

```
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: page,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $.colorbox({
                initialWidth: 700,
                initialHeight: 700,
                current: "{current}/{total}",
                onClosed: function() {
                    $.colorbox.remove();
                },
                html: data
            });
        }
    });
```

This is the code I use for the bxSlider inside the popup:

```
$('#detail_slider').show().bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    controls: true,
    pager: true,
    caption: false,
    slideWidth: 500,
    responsive: true,
    speed: 700,
    pause: 4500,
    auto: true,
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-4x fa-angle-left fa-inverse"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-4x fa-angle-right fa-inverse"></i>',
    prevSelector: '#prevSelector',
    nextSelector: '#nextSelector',
    pagerCustom: '#pager_thumbs',
    onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        $('#pager_' + oldIndex).removeClass("hiTop");
        $('#pager_' + newIndex).addClass("hiTop");
        console.log('old: ' + oldIndex + ' new: ' + newIndex);
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how to disable/remove the bxSlider when I close my colorbox popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I just had to a global variable like:

```
var detailSlider;
```

Then set the slider to that var:

```
detailSlider = $('#detail_slider').colorbox({ SETTINGS });
```

Then add in my ajax onClosed event for colorbox:

```
if(detailSlider.length > 0) {
    detailSlider.destroySlider();
    detailSlider = [];
}
```

Works fine now :)